# Observing a very long pulse

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

In our lecture we are considering the special case of observing a very long pulse propagating through a  dispersive medium. For some reason we say that the spectrum will then be spectrally very narrow (I don't understand what this sentence mean, and I don't understand the correlation between long pulse and narrow spectral interval in the frequency domain). Then if we assume that the dispersion relation does not change drastically we can have a tailor expansion of it:

$$k(\omega)=k(\omega_0)+ \frac {\partial k}{\partial \omega}|_{\omega=\omega_0}(\omega - \omega_0) + \frac 12\frac {\partial^2 k}{\partial \omega^2}|_{\omega=\omega_0}(\omega - \omega_0)^2 +..$$

For the first term it is said:

$$\frac {k(\omega_0)}{\omega_0}=\frac 1{v_{ph}(\omega_0)}$$

describes the phase position of the spreading Pulse. $v_{ph}$ is the phase velocity.

I have a question here. The phase velocity is the propagation speed of each monochromatic wave, in our have packet. If that is correct why do we consider only one $\omega=\omega_0$ when we know that different monochromatic waves which superpositioned together, can have different phase velocity?
And also what is the phase position?

Answer (score 1):

Long pulses have narrow bandwidth in the sense they are constructed primarily using the superposition of a very limited range of frequencies, centred around $\omega_0$.   This follows from the Fourier relation between frequencies and duration:
$$
\Delta f \Delta t\approx 1\, .
$$
There’s a good discussion of this relation in Berkeley Physics’ classic book *Waves* by Crawford.  The logic is that if you want to make apart two waves with a small difference $\omega_1-\omega_2$, you have to wait very long to accumulate enough of a phase difference to tell them apart.

As a result, because the bulk of the amplitude in the superposition is clustered around $\omega_0$, there isn’t much point in considering angular frequencies “far” from $\omega_0$ because they enter with so little weight in the construction of your pulse, and are discarded away in the expression of the phase velocity because “most” of the pulse is at frequencies near $\omega_0$.

Comment: Why do the two waves with similar but different angular velocities (frequencies ) need to have a phase difference? Can't they not have one? And because fundamentally the propagation speed differes slightly, it will come a moment, after a long time, that one wave will be infront of the other, and the wave packet will be distorted. So what is the phase difference ?

Comment: One additional question, for these cases, phase velocities of the superpositioned waves and group velocity of the wave packet are the same?

Comment: the point is you want to compare the contribution to the pulse of a component in  $\cos(\omega_1 t)$ with one with $\cos(\omega_2 t)$ so you can understand the amplitude of each component in your pulse.  The way to do this is to look at times where one component is at a peak while another is at $0$.  If $\omega_1\approx \omega_2$, you will have to wait a very long while for that.  That's one way to understand the origin of $\Delta f\Delta t\approx 1$ in Fourier analysis.

Comment: with narrow bandwidth you are working in a regime where you signal has "almost" only one frequency, so yes the group velocity would be "almost" the same as the phase velocity.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification